# Yocto, Bitbake: List of files, which are to download in the build-process

Tags: proxy, build, yocto-project

I started to set up [Yocto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project) and followed the [official documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/documentation). Problem is the companies' firewall, which doesn't allow me to access all files bitbake wants to download.
Now I try to find out where bitbake wants to fetch its files from.
The bitbake user manual has a ["File Support Download-Section"](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#idm140029332677792), which didn't help me. Furthermore the `bitbake`command itself gives me warnings like

```
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/quilt/quilt-0.64.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
```

However it's impossible to gather a complete list of `WARNINGS`, since after a specific time the build-process stops.

Here my steps to the current state (as said: according to the yocto manual):

1. Installing of all required packages

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-
   multilib \ build-essential chrpath socat libsdl1.2-dev xterm
   $ sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Tunneling Git Protocol through HTTP Connect Proxy (since it is blocked by firewall as well):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install socat #installing socat
   #creating script 'gitproxy':
   #!/bin/sh
   _proxy=<proxyadress>
   _proxyport=<port>

   exec socat STDIO PROXY:$_proxy:$1:$2,proxyport=$_proxyport

   #configuring git with the script:
   $ git config --global core.gitProxy <path_to_script>
   ```
3. Cloning poky (I have yocto running in a VM and inside the VM I install it on a separate `.vdi` (HDD) named `poky`):

   ```
   #Navigating to the disk 'poky':
   cd /media/poky
   sudo git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky

   #yocto project kernel (bare clone)
   $ sudo git clone --bare git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.19 linux-yocto-3.19

   #clone the bare clone
   $ sudo git clone linux-yocto-3.19 my-linux-yocto-3.19-work
   $ cd /media/poky/poky

   # Cloning Metadata in poky-dir
   $ sudo git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-yocto-kernel-extras
   meta-yocto-kernel-extras

   # Cloning BSPs in poky-dir
   $ sudo git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel.git
   ```
4. Build Process

   ```
   # Building images
   # Create branch
   $ git checkout -b fido origin/fido

   # Setting up OE-environment
   $ source oe-init-build-env

   # building OS image
   $ bitbake -k core-image-minimal
   ```

And here we are at the place I don't come further.
Any tipps or workarounds like the one I managed with the Git-Tunneling or is it possible to get a list of the resources from the internet.
**Thank you in Advance !**

(BTW: I am not hundred percent sure wheether this topic belongs to Super Users or to Stack Overflow, however I think you have to be versed in multiple programs etc. like wget, which is used by `bitbake`, so that its better put in here.)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with our proxy with the following configuration:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="<http://ip:port>"
export HTTP_PROXY="<http://ip:port>"
export HTTPS_PROXY="<http://ip:port>"
export FTP_PROXY="<http://ip:port>"
export NO_PROXY="localhost, 127.0.0.1 "
export http_proxy="<http://ip:port>"
export https_proxy="<http://ip:port>"
export ftp_proxy="<http://ip:port>"
export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
export proxy="on"
export use_proxy="yes"
```